# Neo4j database error when loading csv

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

When running this,

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///E:/data.csv" AS line
MERGE (n:MyNode {Name:line.Source})
MERGE (m:MyNode {Name:line.Target})
MERGE (n) -[:TO {dist:line.distance}]-> (m)
```

I got this message:

```
Cannot merge node using null property value for Name
```

Header are:

```
OFFICIAL_SYMBOL_A,OFFICIAL_SYMBOL_B,EXPERIMENTAL_SYSTEM
MAP2K4,FLNC,Two-hybrid
MYPN,ACTN2,Two-hybrid
ACVR1,FNTA,Two-hybrid
GATA2,PML,Two-hybrid
RPA2,STAT3,Two-hybrid
```

Comment: What do the headers look like? Neo4j is also case-sensitive - since the other variables start with a capital, should line.distance be line.Distance?

Comment: capital does not change the issue. I posted the healine. Maybe, this is encoding ?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is that line.property doesn't exist in the CSV (hence the "null" complaint.)

You need to use the field names in the CSV header for this to work. I'm taking a guess at what which header field corresponds to which line.* reference - you'll need to alter this to your situation and apply accordingly:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///E:/data.csv" AS line
MERGE (n:MyNode {Name:line.OFFICIAL_SYMBOL_A})
MERGE (m:MyNode {Name:line.OFFICIAL_SYMBOL_B})
MERGE (n) -[:TO {dist:line.EXPERIMENTAL_SYSTEM}]-> (m)
```